# Javascript Popupbox display problems

Tags: javascript

I am start up programmer in JavaScript. 
I wrote following function to get the popup box on the click of email 
 on abc.php

```
<span class="subbodyheader">E-mail: </span>

            <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
            <!-- 
            // protected email script by Joe Maller(credit)
            // JavaScripts available at http://www.joemaller.com

             emailE=('abc@' + 'XYZ.com')
             document.write('<a onclick="show_confirm()" >' + emailE + '</a>')
             //-->
            </script>




<script type="text/javascript">
 function show_confirm()
 {
    var title = "WXY LLP - Email Disclaimer"
    var msg1="The sending of an email to WXY  ('SAL') lawyer does not create an attorney-client relationship.  " 
    var msg2 = "This website presents general information about SAL and nothing contained in this site is intended as legal advice to you or anyone else and you should not consider it as such. Please be aware that anything you send to anyone at SAL will not be treated as or considered to be confidential from disclosure  unless we have formally agreed to represent you for a particular matter and we have completed a conflicts check. Unless we have created an attorney-client relationship.No information that you  provide to us will prevent SAL from representing a different client in the same matter. "
   //Also, please be aware that until an attorney-client relationship with you exists, SAL is entitled to use any  information that you provide to us in the representation of another client.As a result, you should not send  confidential information to anyone at SAL until you are notified that a formal attorney-client relationship has been established."
    var msg3 =" By clicking 'Ok' in this box and sending this email, you confirm that you have read and understand this notice."

 if (confirm(title + "\n"+ "\n" + msg1 + "\n"  +msg2 + "\n"+ "\n" + msg3 +"\n")==true)
 {
  //window.resizeTo(25,90); //For fixing the window size.
  emailE=('abc@' + 'XYZ.com')
  //document.write('<a href="mailto: ' + emailE + ' " >' + emailE + '</a>') 
  window.location.href = "mailto:abc@XYZ.com"   
 }
 else
 {
  //alert("You pressed Cancel!");
 } 
}
 </script>
```

I have following questions about this --

> 1. When I uncomment the last two line ie. [ //  Also, please be aware that until an attorney-client relationship with you exists, SAL is entitled to use any  information that you provide to us in the representation of another client.As a result, you should not send  confidential information to anyone at SAL until you are notified that a formal attorney-client relationship has been established."] 
>      Entire page shifts to right. I don't know why it is doing so ?
> 2. I want to make var 'title' bold so I use title.bold() but it's not working with 'confirm'? what should I do to achieve this ?
> 3. Is this secure enough to do something like this on the page?